# Creating Array in method

Tags: java, arrays

My class is as follows:

```
public static double Average(double [] temperatures){       
    int size = temperatures.length;         
    double total = 0;       
    for(int i = 0; i <size;i++){            
        total += temperatures[i];       
    }       
    double average =total/size;         
    return size;    
}
```

On main method i used this:

```
Average(1.0,2.5,3.7,4.8);
```

I got following error:

> error: method Average in class Rissam cannot be applied to given
>   types;
>  Average(1.0,2.5,3.7,4.8);
>  required: double[]
>   found: double,double,double,double
>  reason: actual and formal
>   argument lists differ in length

Comment: The answer is in the error message from the compiler, you need to call the method with an array

Comment: BTW, method names start with a lowercase letter

Comment: Another issue is that you are returning the wrong variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the method signature from array to var args:

```
public static double Average(double... temperatures) {
```

if the parameter is a array you must pass and array and not just a list of values.

Answer (score 2):

What you do  is, that you gave four doubles as arguments, but the method needs an array, so you have to put them in an array first :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    double[] array = {1.0,2.5,3.7,4.8};
    Average(array);
}
```

**OR**

You declare the argument of the methode to *double... temperatures* , so the methode will accept the parameters, you give in the code above:

```
public double Average(double... temperatures)
```

Comment: Yes, or declare the argument as `double... temperatures`

Answer (score 0):

Need to pass arg as double array.

## Option 1

Change `Average(1.0,2.5,3.7,4.8);` to `Average(new double[]{1.0,2.5,3.7,4.8});`

## Option 2

Change method signature to `public static double Average(double ...temperature)`

Answer (score 0):

Change your method as-

```
public static double Average(double ... temperatures){       
int size = temperatures.length;         
double total = 0;       
for(int i = 0; i <size;i++){            
total += temperatures[i];       
}       
double average =total/size;         
return size;    
}
```

where ... represent variable length arguments. it is equivalent to array.
or either change method calling by passing an array